# What is the most recommended django/oauth package for Facebook and Twitter integration?

Tags: django, facebook, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for a django/oauth project which would allow for open authentication to at least Twitter and Facebook (other services would be a bonus).  It appears there was a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197924/what-is-the-best-oauth-django-library) started by [TIMEX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179736/timex) in Febuary 2010 with a few different package recommendations.

Since it has been approximately a year and a half since the originator first posed the question, I'd like to ask again, hoping that time may have given to some more robust packages.

Some packages mentioned from the previous thread:

- http://code.google.com/p/django-gigyauth - Last updated July 18, 2010
- https://github.com/simonw/django-openid  - Last updated Jan 12, 2010
- https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth - Last updated July 5, 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) is the most widely used. Check [djangopackages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/) for a more detailed overview of what is available.

Comment: Thank you for your response. djangopackages appears to be a great site for me to find what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have to go with https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth. It's the best maintained and easiest to set up. http://djangopackages.com is going to that for authentication shortly. Why Because it rocks.

Yeah, I'm one of the people behind http://djangopackages.com. :)

Comment: Agreed django-social-auth rocks. Lots of sites available by default and super easy to write more. I even started a grid to track additional backends: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/social-auth-backends/

Answer (score 0):

Django Facebook is the most mature for Facebook authentication, it only does facebook though, none of the other systems.

If you are looking for additional platforms (and don't require additional facebook integration) than socialauth would work for you